# After renaming a model and changing all references to the model, a reference remains to the previous name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I had a model called Person after following a tutorial online. After a while we decided that it was more sensible to rename it to User. I went through the code base and did the following:

1. Renamed all instances of Person to User, person to user, People to Users and people to users, taking care not to clobber anything unrelated.
2. Renamed all model files appropriately.

I have another model called session:

session belongs_to user

and

user has_many sessions

Prior to running migrations git grep -i person / people and find | grep person / people just return migrations so I'm sure that I have renamed everything properly.

When I go to create a new user which subsequently creates a session I get the following error:

unknown attribute: user_id

Running git grep again I find that the foreign key in sessions is still person_id

```
create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|                                                                                                                             
    t.integer  "person_id
    t.string   "ip_address"                                                                                
    t.string   "path"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you see in console, when you type User ?

Comment: Did u recreate ur database after changes .... drop your database and re -run migrations

Comment: @Emrah: User(id: integer, username: string, salt: string, encrypted_password: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, email: string, profile_image_path: string, forename: string, surname: string, avatar_file_name: string, avatar_content_type: string, avatar_file_size: integer, avatar_updated_at: datetime, about: string)

Comment: @JonathanEvans sorry, i mean Session not User.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just do in a migration

```
def change
   rename_column :sessions, :person_id, :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the name of an association, but not the name of the underlying column, you have to make it explicit in the association:

```
class Session 
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "person_id", :inverse_of => :sessions
end

class User
  has_many :sessions, :foreing_key => "person_id", :inverse_of => :user
end
```

Answer (score -2):

in sessions table, you have to change person_id to user_id,

```
for that you have to add new migration for adding user_id and remove person_id

def change
  add_column :sessions, :user_id, :integer
  remove_column :sessions, :person_id, :integer
end
```

Comment: Will this not break the original belongs_to association?

Comment: Accepted the answer of Aayush as his answer doesn't involve loosing data.